# Why are there multiple ways to save polygonized 3D model data?

Tags: cad

In CAD, there are multiple file formats only for the scope of saving polygonized models in three dimensions.

For example, there is the [Object File Format](http://segeval.cs.princeton.edu/public/off_format.html) and furthermore, there is the much more famous [STL](http://www.fabbers.com/tech/STL_Format) format.

What are the different (most important) use cases and reasons to use especially one of them?

Comment: Speed depending on how the data is interpreted, how the results will be plotted, drawn or published ie what format later or subsequent programs want...

Comment: I think this question needs to be made clearer, it is too broad presently.

Comment: STL is perhaps common but also, spectacularily bad format. It may work for many tings but just barely, reason being that they forgot to specify how a few things should be handled. Also the format entirely ignores point sharing. As a result the format needs to be interpretted and often fixed before use. STL is not really any good for anything other than 3D printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The great thing about standards is there are so many to choose from" attr. Andrew Tannenbaum.

Some CAD formats were deliberately developed to be proprietary so as to enhance sales of someone's CAD software.  Some were developed with certain applications in mind.  Others were developed ad hoc.

For what it's worth, there are probably 10X as many "standard" image file formats as there are CAD formats.  Something we all have to live with -- and a gold mine for those who sell format-conversion software tools.

Comment: I beg to disagree, there is almost cerainly more 3D formats. But upvoted anyway.

Comment: @joojaa  I really didn't want to know that :-)

Answer (score 0):

The formats have different functions. While it is true that some of the formats duplicate functionality it would be a mistake to think all the formats are interchageable and serve same purpose.

For example stl is the file format intended for 3D printing. All it does is store a bunch of sepaarate triangles. It is meant to be extremely easy to dump. But it does not contain any other reliable info. The fileformat forces you to rebuild all semantic info that may have been in the mesh. The format is nearly unusable for anything other it was intended for.

Usually you then have one or more formats meant for rendering like the obj format which resembles OFF you linked but has info on rudimentary material properties, uv maps normals, connectivity and so on. This makes the format much more usable. But alas unlike STL there is no binary version so these can become really big for highly tesselated meshes.

Then you usually have the intermediate format needed to make 3D PDF files, you get it for free if you intend to support 3D PDF, its nearly useless outside the context.